# Toggle capslock with command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, command, capslock

I'm trying to enable capslock with a console command, is there a possibility to do so? I found `setleds +/-caps` but that only works in a non-graphical environment sadly.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see [here](https://www.securitronlinux.com/bejiitaswrath/how-to-toggle-the-caps-lock-key-with-the-command-line-in-linux-mint/) that `xdotool` can do it:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Toggle the CapsLock effect (lock uppercase) with

```
xdotool key Caps_Lock
```